# Your connection is not secure Certbot / LetsEncrypt

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, certbot

I have enabled SSL for my `https://example.com` and that works fine, but if somone try's to enter `https://www.example.com` I get the message: Your connection is not secure.

Is there a way to redirect all WWW to non-http before checking the SSLcertificate? or does this need to be done on the domain dns settings?

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was sure there must be a duplicate candidate, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: @JennyD I think we have had many more questions about forwarding from an SSL domain without having a certificate for the domain. I am not sure the one you found is the best such question. But it's not like it is easy to search for possible duplicates.

Comment: @kasperd There are indeed multiple such questions. Maybe it's time for a new canonical...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need either a second certificate for the subdomain, or one certificate that is valid for both. There is no way around it. The redirect happens after the SSL connection is established, so you need a working certificate for a working redirect.

With certbot you can create such a certificate by providing the `-d` parameter multiple times:

```
certbot-auto -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

Answer (score -2):

you can make all the WWW requests redirect to `https://example.com`

so in the virtual host for port 80 you set the `serverName` with `example.com` and the `serverAlias` to `www.example.com` and then redirect to `https://example.com` which has the valid certificates

or if you want to run WWW over https you can do as Gerald said and generate certificate for both domain and it's sub domain

Comment: This won't work if someone directly accesses `https://www.example.com/` - the SSL verification comes before the redirect.

Comment: yea you are right sorry for missing this point